# Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2021

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Quantum Computing Stack Exchange began the nomination stage for a special election on June 14 to bring in one more moderator.

For full details of the process, see the announcement on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

Starting on June 14, users can nominate themselves. Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the `discussion` and `election tags`.)

On June 21, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidates. If there aren't any nominees this week we'll extend the nomination period by an additional week. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-moderator-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-pa), but I doubt that will come up.)

If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on June 29.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

This being *pro tempore*, I suppose there is an expectation that at some point in the future there will be *non pro tempore* elections, in which the *pro tempore* mods will have to rerun, correct?

Is there any fixed schedule as to when that will happen? I suppose this is akin to asking whether there are fixed criteria in place for graduation to happen. I know things have been changing in this regard; the latest discussions on the matter I found are in *[What should the criteria be for Stack Exchange sites to leave beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331718/276202)* and *[Congratulations to our 29 oldest beta sites - They're now no longer beta!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/276202)*, but I cannot see any "official position" being stated there.

Comment: Yes all *pro tempore* mods will have to run for re-election at graduation, and there's no fixed criteria anymore for graduation (it used to be 10 questions/day for "long enough"). It will probably be many years from now though: space.se has still not graduated after several years longer than QCSE has existed, and Artificial Intelligence SE would also graduate before QCSE.

Comment: Correct. No ETA right now on site graduation. We will be looking into Beta sites in the future and will communicate when we have updates on graduations. When there is a graduation election Pro Temp mods will renominate themselves.